# Add element to List that is inside a Map (ImmutableJS)

Tags: list, dictionary, reactjs, redux, immutable.js

This is a example of what my state looks like:

```
  state = {
    messages: [
       {name: 'Bruce', content: 'Hello'},
       {name: 'Clark', content: 'World'}
    ]
  }
```

I am writing a reducer that will take the ADD_MESSAGE action and add a message to the message list. I would like to take into account the case where the 'messages' key is not defined. I am just starting to use ImmutableJS.

This is how I wrote my function:

```
 // This is really bad
 const addMessage = (state, message) => {
    let mutableState = state.toJS();
    if(mutableState.messages){
      mutableState.messages.push(message);
    }else{
      mutableState = {messages: [message]}
    }

    return fromJS(mutableState);
 }
```

I'm pretty sure there is a better way to do that. It should work whether my state argument is Immutable or not. Any idea? Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a possible implementation:

```
const addMessage = (state, message) => 
    state.update('messages', Immutable.List(), 
        msgs => msgs.push(Immutable.Map(message)));
```

The 2nd arg passed to `update` is the default value if the key doesn't exist, and the 3rd argument is a closure to take the current value for the key (or default value) and perform the required update. The code also converts the message into an `Immutable.Map`, but you might prefer to use an `Immutable.Record` type.

See https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Map/update for more info on `update`. `updateIn` is also very useful for updating store state, as are `set`, `merge`, `setIn` and `mergeIn`.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Immutable.Record is exactly what I was looking for, using a map seemed wrong!